# SQL Select from all rows except this ID doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to show all rows except the one with the id '64'. But it shows the row with the id '64' too.

My SQL code is:

```
SELECT * from uploads where status='1' AND id != '64' AND typ = 'video' AND tags LIKE '%dad%' OR tags LIKE '%spiegel%' OR tags LIKE '%wasser%' order by timestamp DESC LIMIT 4
```

TABLE SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS uploads (
  id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id varchar(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  title varchar(500) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  description varchar(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  file varchar(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  url varchar(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  thumbnail varchar(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  tags varchar(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  place varchar(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  categorie_id varchar(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  storage varchar(120) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  file_storage varchar(120) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  video_length varchar(120) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  status varchar(120) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  timestamp varchar(120) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  typ varchar(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  comments varchar(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  premium varchar(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=72 ;


INSERT INTO uploads (id, user_id, title, description, file, url, thumbnail, tags, place, categorie_id, storage, file_storage, video_length, status, timestamp, typ, comments, premium) VALUES
(1, '1', 'test', 'test', '', '0', '', 'dad, tags, wasser, spiegel', '', '0', '1983349', '0', '0', '1', '1467016374', 'image', '1', '0'),
(64, '1', 'Taddy', '', '0', '', '', 'dad, spiegel, wasser', '', '0', '0', '0', '-', '1', '1467387022', 'video', '1', '1');
```

SQL Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f3b54/1

But it doesn't work :( Can anyone help me

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Can you add your table? Thanks

Comment: I have added it  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to this syntax (`<>` and `64` as `integer`) and you also might add parenthesis to your last condition like bellow:

```
SELECT * FROM uploads 
WHERE status='1' 
AND id <> 64 
AND typ = 'video' 
AND (tags LIKE '%dad%' OR tags LIKE '%spiegel%' OR tags LIKE '%wasser%')
ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 4
```

What's the differance between `!=` and `<>`?

Technically they function the same if you’re using MS SQL aka T-SQL. If you're using it in stored procedures there is no performance reason to use one over the other. It then comes down to personal preference. I prefer to use <> as it is ANSI compliant.

You can find links to the various ANSI standards at...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL

Comment: Nope. No rows are found

Comment: Can you post your table?

Comment: What is the type of your `id` column?

Comment: I have posted the SQL Code for the Table

Comment: See my change, try to change it to `64` witout the apostrophes, `int` instead of `varchar`.

Comment: **You should't get any result** your first row in the table doesn't implement all the conditions, its `typ` is `image` and not `video` and the second row won't come up because the `id` is equal to `64`. Your query is totally correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use parentheses:

```
SELECT *
from uploads
where status = '1' AND id <> '64' AND typ = 'video' AND
      (tags LIKE '%dad%' OR tags LIKE '%spiegel%' OR tags LIKE '%wasser%')
order by timestamp DESC
LIMIT 4;
```

If you are not familiar with boolean logic and precedence, then always use parentheses when mixing `AND` and `OR`.

Note that I prefer `<>` for the inequality operator.  Many databases support `!=` as well, but that is not standard SQL.  Also, if `status` and/or `id` are numeric, then don't put single quotes around the values.  Get in the habit of not mixing data types.

Your expression is parsed as:

```
where (status = '1' AND id <> '64' AND typ = 'video' AND tags LIKE '%dad%') OR
      (tags LIKE '%spiegel%') OR
      (tags LIKE '%wasser%')
```

In addition, your query suggests a deeper problem -- storing multiple tags in a single field.  This is a very bad idea.  You should have a separate table, say `UploadTags` with one row per "upload" and one "tag".

Comment: Shows still the row with the id 64

Comment: @DavidJason . . . The first query cannot show the row with id as `'64'`.  Your issue must be with how "64" is represented in the database.  Perhaps there are hidden characters or leading zeros.

Comment: @DavidJason your fiddle shows that you haven't put in the parentheses, which are required to force the desired order of evaluation of `where` conditions, as 2 people have told you. `and` takes precedence over `or`, so without parentheses, your original code is equivalent to 'filter to things matching (this, that, `and` Tag 1) - **`or`** anything with Tag 2 `or` anything with Tag 3 `or` anything with Tag 4...'. by adding parentheses around the `or`, you will change this so it's 'show me things matching ( this, that and (any of these Tags) )`